# Transaction with binded thread connection in Spring

Tags: spring, jdbc, transactions, spring-transactions

I want to bind a connection to a thread, and use that connection for any JdbcTemplate calls, to finally commit the changes or do a rollback.

I'm declaring all sentences from a Groovy script, so I can't control how many SQL query will be call, that's why I have to used this method and not a TransactionalTemplate or something like that. this script will call a helper class that will use that connection and JdbcTemplate, let's call that class *SqlHelper*.

Right now my non-working-as-needed solution is call from groovy script to that *SqlHelper* to initialize a transaction:

```
initTransaction(ecommerce)
```

which calls

```
public void initTransaction(DataSource dataSource) {
    DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    transactionDefinition.setReadOnly(false);
    transactionDefinition.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE);
    // dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    // dataSourceTransactionManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
    // dataSourceTransactionManager.setTransactionSynchronization(TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_COMMITTED);
    // dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);

    try {
        Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction(connection, transactionDefinition);
    } catch (CannotGetJdbcConnectionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

After that the script will call some SQL operations, like

```
sqlUpdate(ecommerce, insertSentence, insertParams)
```

which calls

```
public Integer update(DataSource dataSource, String sql, Map<String, Object> paramMap) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource).update(sql, paramMap);
}
```

Finally I want to finish the transaction committing the changes using

```
commitTransaction(dataSource)
```

which calls

```
public void commitTransaction(DataSource dataSource) {
     Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
     try {
     connection.commit();
     } catch (Exception e) {
     rollbackTransaction(dataSource);
     }
    // DataSourceUtils.resetConnectionAfterTransaction(connection, TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_DEFAULT);
    //        SimpleTransactionStatus transactionStatus = new SimpleTransactionStatus(false);
    //        try {
    //            dataSourceTransactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);
    //            jta.commit(transactionStatus);
    //        } catch (TransactionException e) {
    //             dataSourceTransactionManager.rollback(transactionStatus);
    //            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    //        }
}

private void rollbackTransaction(DataSource dataSource) {
    Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
    try {
        connection.rollback();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    DataSourceUtils.resetConnectionAfterTransaction(connection, TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_DEFAULT);
}
```

I left commented blocks of some testing to show you what approaches I tried. I don't know very well how Spring transaction works, so I'm just trying different things and trying to learn how all this stuff works... I will provide you more information if you want ;)

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

As M. Denium suggested, that's what I have for now:

I declared the variable, using the `TransactionStatus` as ThreadSafe and finally solved as:

```
private DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = null;
private DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = null;
private static final ThreadLocal<TransactionStatus> transactionStatus = new ThreadLocal<TransactionStatus>() {
    @Override
    protected TransactionStatus initialValue() {
        return null;
    }
};
```

And then using the same call from Groovy script, using the helper methods:

```
public void initTransaction(DataSource dataSource) {
    dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    transactionDefinition.setReadOnly(false);
    transactionDefinition.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE);
    dataSourceTransactionManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
    dataSourceTransactionManager.setTransactionSynchronization(TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_UNKNOWN);
    dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    transactionStatus.set(dataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(null));
}

public void commitTransaction() {
    try {
        LOG.info("Finishing transaction...");
        dataSourceTransactionManager.commit(transactionStatus.get());
        dataSourceTransactionManager.getDataSource().getConnection().close();
        LOG.info("Done.");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        dataSourceTransactionManager.rollback(transactionStatus.get());
        throw new RuntimeException("An exception during transaction. Rolling back.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do it like that, you are making it way to complex. Let Spring start a transaction before anything else, use a `JdbcTemplate` to execute code and when finished commit it. You shouldn't mess around with starting a transaction or getting a connection yourself, spring is already doing that for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But Spring will commit any query from groovy script whenever the helper is called. So my approach was get a connection and reuse it without autocommit to manually finish the transaction. Also, I can't programmatically program a JdbcTemplate because I don't know what the user would like to execute.

Comment: The script knows when to start en when to end, instead of messing around with connections yourself, let spring handle that. You can still use springs transaction management (which you are trying to work around) and leverage all the benefits. It will save you code, time and headaches.

Comment: Also performance wise it isn't a smart thing to create a `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` because that is quite a heavy object to construct. (It analyzes a database connection to determine which database , type, version is being used. It does this each time an instance is created and that proces is quite slow).

Comment: Ok, I see your point. But, I'm not getting how to let Spring handle the transaction. I forget to say that the SqlHelper also receives the dataSource, because I don't know anything about what the user script will want to do. I tried to use PlatformTransactionManager also, and I worked perfectly. But I can't use it because user wouldn't be able to interact with the transaction.

Comment: On one hand you want to guide the user and on the other hand he has to manually control the transactions, that is a bit strange. I as a user would be confused.

Comment: The purpose of this behaviour is that the user will declare when he wants to start a transaction, then the user (I assume I need get the connection, that's why I did that way) will call the SqlHelper to execute any query he wants (the validation and all that stuff it's on him) and finally, the user will declare that the transaction should be committed with changes he did. Lets say, I'm only the intermediary between his script and the dataSource he wants to use, but I need to control when commit the transaction (or rollback if necessary).

Comment: You can still do that with a `PlatformTransactionManager`. But still it feels very convoluted and trying to use framework in a way it wasn't or isn't intended to be used. Groovy already has sql support and can run multiple queries in a [single transaction](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withTransaction(groovy.lang.Closure)), what is wrong with the default support?

Comment: Yeah, I know. But user doesn't have to know how declare a transaction in Groovy, that why I'm using that Helper. Also, this is just a little piece or a bigger webapp, but an important one. Anyway, I tried with DataSourceTransactionManager, as you can see in the OP, without success, any query executes in its own transaction. That class says "Will bind a Connection to the thread if transaction synchronization is active, e.g. when running within a JTA transaction)" so I think this where I should look at, right?

Comment: No you shouldn't... So he hasn't have to know groovy but has to know in java how to start a transaction (because that is basically what you are telling them). Still doesn't feel right and feels like you should actually be training your users. When using the `PlatformTransactionManager` to start a transaction you get a `TransactionStatus` object, you need the user to keep a ref to this and pass it to a commit method (instead of the `DataSource`). But as mentioned it feels wrong and like a contraption to work around a working and imho easier way.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm saying. But trust me, that's what user wants. They have to know groovy but in a very simple way, just a couple of groovy concepts and all the stuff will be handled by using injected helpers. I will implement PlatformTransactionManager, as you say. But permit me one question, where should I use the dataSource to get the database connection then? Thank you for your help M. Deinum

Comment: You shouldn't. Also you don't have to implement `PlatformTransactionManager` you should use the `DatasourcePlatformTransactionManager`. That will also take care of binding the connection etc. `JdbcTemplate` will detect it and use it.

Comment: Still I would also try to convince users there is a better and easier way (you wouldn't have to implement anything as it would be working out-of-the-box).

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. But I need to provide to the user information about the transactions, so I can't let him handle the transaction on its way because I need to know how the transaction interacts with the database. And it's easier to teach init transaction with "initTransaction(datasource)" method and commit with "docommit()" that all the transaction logic I think. Anyway, I'll keep in mind your suggestion, which I'm agree too.

Comment: Finally I did what you said, and where 100% right. I was doing ok all the time, but I wasn't keeping the reference to the `TransactionStatus` (I didn't know I had to). Now I do everything works fine, don't know why I can't catch the exceptions, but at least the commits are working ok. If you want to provide the answer I will check it as correct, and I will update the post with the final code. Thank you very much for your time and help M. Denium.

Comment: Als why is it easier to tech additional classes and framework then learn them proper Groovy... sql.withTransaction(... all your statements here ...). reads a lot easier than `startTx(datasource). keep references, do things, commit(datasource)`. The first is more concise and easier to read, without having to define additional classes. It just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to reimplement the things that are already implemented by the transaction abstraction of Spring. Simply use the proper `PlatformTransactionManager` (you can probably grab that from an `ApplicationContext`) keep a reference to the `TransactionStatus` instead of a `DataSource` and use that to commit/rollback.

```
public TransactionStatus initTransaction() {
    return transactionManager.getTransaction(null);
}

public void commit(TransactionStatus status) {
    transactionManager.commit(status);
}
```

Instead of passing the `TransactionStatus` around you could also store it in a `ThreadLocal` and retrieve it in the `commit` method. This would ease the pain.

Another tip you shouldn't be creating `JdbcTemplate`s and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`s those are heavy objects to create. Upon construction they consult a connection to determine which database and version this is needed for the exception conversion. So performance wise this isn't a smart thing to do. Create a single instance and reuse, the templates are thread safe so you would only be needing a single instance.

However I would strongly argue that you should actually be using Groovy and not to try to work around it. Groovy has the [`Sql`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) class that can help you. You already have access to the `DataSource` so doing something like this would be all that is needed.

```
def sql = new Sql(dataSource);
sql.withTransaction {
    sql.execute "INSERT INTO city (name, state, founded_year) VALUES ('Minneapolis', 'Minnesota', 1867)"
    sql.execute "INSERT INTO city (name, state, founded_year) VALUES ('Orlando', 'Florida', 1875)"
    sql.execute "INSERT INTO city (name, state, founded_year) VALUES ('Gulfport', 'Mississippi', 1887)"
}
```

This is plain Groovy, no need to develop additional classes or to write extensive documentation to get it working. Just Groovy...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you just answered, but now I'm facing a new problem. I can't (or I don't know how) declare a new transaction after committing a new one. If I do declare a new transaction, the following calls to _SqlHelper_ will be committed automatically in a transaction (without waiting to `commit(TransactionStatus status)`)

Comment: A call to `initTransaction` should create a new transaction, make sure you are passing around the correct status object.

Comment: Forget it, it was my fault. Everything works fine. Thank you!